# Как называется повар, готовящий пиццу?

Tags: терминология

Недавно увидел объявление в кафе: "Требуется пиццерист". Прозвучало как-то смешно. А как на самом деле называется повар, готовящий пиццу? Наверняка у него есть какие-то правильное название.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хорошего повара называют маэстро. ***Маэстро ля Пицца***. 
Плохого - никак не называют.

Была аналогичная шутка про шаурму.  Поскольку распространена повсеместно, тащу сюда без указания конкретного авторства.

Шаурмист - низший класс, работает плохо, руки не моет, жадничает. В
производстве использует собачье мясо, плесневелый лаваш и просроченный
майонез.
Шаурмачо - наиболее распространенный вид. Шумный товарищ с волосатой
грудью и кавказским акцентом.
Шаурмейкер - обитает на западе, в производстве использует новейшие
технологии. В продукции много холестерина.
Шаурмэн - производство сопровождает пафосными монологами, расхаливает
качество продукции.
Шаурман - первый подвид специаизируется на производстве кошерной шаурмы.
Второй подвид ничего сам не делает, а только жрет, при отсутствии
продукта чувствует себя крайне плохо.
Шаурмастер - редкий вид, работает быстро но аккуратно, высокое качество
продукции гарантировано.
Шаурматор - андроид, молчит и работает, производит абсолютно одинаковые
порции. В продукции иногда попадаются ржавые гайки и куски проводов.
Шаурмахер - вместо мяса использует копченые сардельки с кислой капустой.
К каждой порции - кружка пива бесплатно.
Шаурмейстер - высшая каста, гроссо маэстро, умывальников начальник и
мочалок командир. В природе не встречается.

(С)перто

Добавлю: 
шаурмье 
шаурмятник
шаурмовщик
шаурмян

Comment: Хорошая шутка! :)

Comment: Кстати, забавный факт. В Вологде продают **шаурму**, а в соседнем Череповце (200 км) уже **шаверму**.

Comment: Это еще вопрос, кто кому соседний. 
Череповец - кород вполне себе самодостаточный, даром, что не областной центр.
А двести км - это простите, что от Москвы до Рязани. Другая область, другой мир.    
ЗВ От Вологды до Череповца - 140 км. Если по прямой.

Comment: Для Русского Севера 200 км - не расстояние. А соседи они друг другу, "в Череповце работают, в Вологде отдыхают". Культурные и экономические связи  - значительны, область-то одна и та же. Это у Устюга свой диалект, а у Вологды и Череповца лексических и фонетических различий в современности нет. Это примерно тоже, что на севере Москвы говорили так, а на юге - уже по другому.

Comment: Вологда - не Север. 
А череповец - современный индустриальный город.

Comment: Вологда - это "Культурная столица Русского Севера. Расположена на 60-й широте на притоке Северной Двины, природная зона - тайга, средняя годовая температура - +3 (в Москве - +6), морозы за -30 бывают почти каждый год, относится к Северному экономическому району и бюджетники получают северные надбавки.

Череповец - город индустриальный, но не современный. Большинство построек относится к брежневской эпохе. Виды Череповца можно увидеть, например, в фильме "Груз 200", городские пейзажи снимали именно в Городе металлургов. Даже Вологда выглядит посовременней Череповца.

Comment: Ага, вы еще про Деда Мороза вспомните.
То-то и оно что културная. А Ваш офонаризм про двести километров - это для Сибири, где на эти двести км из всех культурных объектов - река да берлога. да

Comment: В данном случае, мне явно видней.

Comment: Шаверма — это питерский диалект))) Но у нас говорят "шаурма". И все-таки более правильный вариант . Турция под боком, да и тюркоязычные татары говорят именно "шаурма" — в тюркском слове не может быть ударения не на последний слог.

Comment: А какая нам, русским, разница, как говорят в татары или турки? Если слова не русеют, то это плохой знак для языка.

Answer (score 4):

Можно называть "пиццайоло" (итальянский вариант) или "пиццмейкер" (английский). Хотя "пиццерист", мне нравится больше, просто и понятно.

Answer (score 3):

Пиццедел (потребитель - пиццеед) :)))))))

Comment: Лучший вариант.

Answer (score 1):

В литературным языке на правах нормативного это слово еще не закрепилось.В разговорном языке ближе к русскому все же пиццерист.

Answer (score 1):

Ну конечно же, *пиццерист* это ошибка, причём обидная. Как и *пиццераст*... Обычно нас называют *пиццер, пиццайло, пиццмейкер, повар пиццы*. Пицца выделяется на производстве как отдельная позиция. По официальному итальянскому рецепту выпекается в дровяной печи (помпейская) при t +400 всего 2 минуты (*Маргарита и Ала маринара*). Всё остальное уже не original.

Comment: А это как-то определяет правильность формы пиццерист?))) Ещ\у замечу, что ничего оригинального итальянского в названии пиццмейкер или пиццайло быть не может. Есть слово pizzaiolo (пиццай**о**ло) - но это повар пиццы как "ширпотреба" - т.е. простой и дешевой для непритязательных потребителей.

Comment: @behemothus, Я спросил у итальянцев. Ответ таков: pizzaiolo – это официальное название повара, который готовит пиццу. Как правило, они проходят длительные курсы и практику, ведь, им запрещается работать скалкой, а замешивать тесто нужно только вручную или подбрасывая и крутя в воздухе. Это престижная работа.

Comment: @М_Г ничего против такого названия на итальянском не имею. Но сильно сомневаюсь, что это название для пиццевого маэстро. ))) В москве есть сеть дешевых ресторанчиков с таким названием. Вот не запомнил, как называли аналогичного персонажа в голландии - там общедоступные пиццерии на каждом углу...

Comment: @behemothus Есть рестораны с таким названием и в других странах. Можно и дешевый ресторан для красоты назвать высоким словом, тем более иностранным . Снижает ли это значение слова?

Comment: @М_Г *Снижает ли это значение слова?* - я не могу ответить на этот вопрос. Вообще не понимаю при чем тут "сниженность". Я еще пять лет назад (тогда, кстати, рекомендуемый "формат" ответов сильно отличался от нынешнего) говорил о *сомнительности обобщения итальянского слова*, которое у меня явно ассоциируется с ширпотребом, на мастера пиццы вообще. Позиция у меня не изменилась. дешевые ресторанчики с таким названием - аргумент в пользу моей концепции.